# unable to pull .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore, git-pull

I've modified my .gitignore file from my VPS. Then I've commit the change and pushed to remote repo:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m ".gitignore changed"
git push -u origin --all
```

and then, I pull it to localhost:

```
git pull
```

But I get the next error:

```
error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore' (Permission denied)
```

I've tried changing permissions of .gitignore local file to 0777, but doesn't work.
The file in remote repo has been changed, but not in my local file
What could be the problem? and how could be solved?

Comment: Can you delete the file manually? I.e. `rm .gitignore`?

Comment: Yes. Now it is "unable to create file" when try to pull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was easy:

```
sudo git pull
```

**Edit:**

I had probably wrong permissions (better said, owner) in the `.git` directory.
It's better to change the owner of this directory and files instead:

```
sudo chown -R yourGitUser ./.git
```

Comment: Bypassing the permissions system by being root, or changing the permissions so you are allowed to do the action is essentially the same ;)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a permission problem. Try applying 0775 rights to the `.git` folder, not only `.gitignore`.